# vlookup for each item in comma-separated list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns of data — id's and data values. I can get vlookup to work if I want to return the correct fruit if I provide an id, but I need to also be able to account for cases where multiple values are provided as well.

Put another way, I need to be able to run my vlookup on each item in a comma-separated list in another cell.

| id | fruit |  | input | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2835 | apples |  | 4792 | pears |
| 2232 | bananas |  | 2835 | apples |
| 3244 | peaches |  | 1199,3244,2835,4790 | should be: oranges,peaches,etc… |
| 4792 | pears |  |  |  |
| 1199 | oranges |  |  |  |

[image]

[Lookup multiple values in a single cell (comma separated) and then return the values to a single cell (also comma separated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417099/lookup-multiple-values-in-a-single-cell-comma-separated-and-then-return-the-va)

[Vlookup using a comma separated search key in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74035706/vlookup-using-a-comma-separated-search-key-in-google-sheets)

I feel like I'm very close with the linked posts above, but I keep getting errors. This is what I have, though I'm open to an alternative approach (or something using Google Apps Script)

```
=arrayformula(left(concatenate(vlookup(split(D4,","),$A$2:$B$6,2,false)&","),len(concatenate(vlookup(split(D4,","),$A$2:$B$6,2,false)&","))-1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution using `XLOOKUP` function:

```
=JOIN(",",ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP(SPLIT(D4,","),A:A,B:B,"",0,1)))
```

**Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(D4),vlookup(D4,A:B,2,0),join(",",query(A:B,"Select B where A = "&JOIN(" OR A = ",split(D4,",",1,1)))))
```

If D4 is a number (so it's not varios values) it does the VLOOKUP, if it is not it split the values and inserts them in a query, then join the results with commas again.

If you want it for the whole column:

```
=BYROW(D2:D,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",IF(isnumber(each),vlookup(each,A:B,2,0),join(",",query(A:B,"Select B where A = "&JOIN(" OR A = ",split(each,",",1,1))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Formula that works in Excel:

=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(D4,",",","),","),A:A,B:B,"",0,1))

The SUBSTITUTE command was added to allow for different separators in source and destination strings.  e.g. you can replace ", " with "," and then reverse that on the TEXTJOIN.

Answer (score -2):

For me, In excel the below worked fine.

```
=ARRAYTOTEXT(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(D2,","),B:B,A:A,"NA",0,1))
```

[Screenshot of the excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7c3a.png)